# Extract nested objects in an object using dataset api in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm new in Spark, i'm trying the dataset api and i would like to know if it's possible to extract nested objects in an object using the dataset api.
For example, let's say i have an object of type A et an object of type B as below

```
case class A(a: String, b: Integer)
case class B(c: Array[A])
```

I have a dataset containing objects of class B : Dataset[B]
I would like to apply some transformations to get all the objects of type A in my final dataset : Dataset[A]
I tried this but it does not work

```
bs.map(b => b.a.map(x => x))
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first explode the `B's Array[A]` into rows and cast them to DataSet[A]

```
## 'bs' Dataset 
+--------------------------+
|c                         |
+--------------------------+
|[[value1, 1], [value2, 2]]|
+--------------------------+


val testDF = bs.select(explode($"c"))

## 'testDF' Dataframe
+-----------+
|        col|
+-----------+
|[value1, 1]|
|[value2, 2]|
+-----------+


val asDF = test_df.withColumn("a", col("col.a")).withColumn("b", col("col.b")).drop("col").as[A]

## 'asDF' Dataset
+------+---+
|     a|  b|
+------+---+
|value1|  1|
|value2|  2|
+------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me ;) . I did test_df.select($"col.*").as[A], a little bit faster :)